# Where can I get non "live" ISOs for 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am looking for a non "live" ISO for 20.04.  When I upgraded to 18.04   I found that the live ISO did not allow me to set several important options  and I ended up using ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso.  I am now looking for a 20.04 equivalent.

Now that I have "remembered" what the original issue was I will try the "live" ISO and see if the 20.04 one has solved the issue.

I am installing via idrac off remotely mounted media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the **legacy** directory.  These images (based on `debian-installer`) will no longer be provided for releases after Ubuntu Focal.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/

There are some other questions related to this around, and some discussion in the Discourse topics at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/server/17/l/latest